# I DO want to plot missing data

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe

I have dataframe, one column has a timestamp and another a float.
data type:

```
In[15]: type (df_wave['TIMESTAMP'][0])
Out[15]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp
In[16]: type (df_wave['wave_hPa_Avg(1)'][0])
Out[16]: numpy.float64
```

data looks like:

```
In[19]: df_wave['TIMESTAMP'][0]
Out[19]: Timestamp('2015-07-03 7:00:20.200000')
In[20]: df_wave['wave_hPa_Avg(1)'][0]
Out[20]: 155.19999999999999
```

Question:

I have big chunks of data missing. From 19:00 at night till 07:00 in the morning, there is no data. However, when I plot this, I get one continues graph. 
How can I plot the data in such a manner, were python automatically interpolates the missing dates, and displays the gaps in the graph where there is no data.

My worry is, is that I will have to manually add all the missing dates, and NaN-values. As a side note, its good to know that the frequency of my time measurements is 5 Hz... (5 times per sec, so that's a ton of data points in a twelve hour time frame)

Comment: are you after [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)?

Comment: Ok...maybe, I've never seen this function before. I'll check it out. See if I can make anything useful. Cheers.

Comment: Basically you can resample your df to a new time resolution and depending on whether you're up/downsampling will fill or add `NaN` values, this seems to be what you're after I think

Comment: Sweet! That makes sense. I'll try it ASAP. Once I have the correct code, I'll post it.

Comment: `df_wave.set_index('TIMESTAMP').plot()` will show the gaps, I think.

Comment: Interesting, it does seem to work, I don't understand why though. 
Indeed there is space where there isn't any data. 

However, although there is space where there is no data, it draws a straight horizontal line. This looks quite strange in a graph that shows the tide over a time frame of 3 days, ie. An oscillating line that peaks 3 time, but at each peak, a horizontal line occurs (where the data is missing). Do you think it is possible not to show these data points?